# How do I fix local variable referenced before assignment error within my discord command

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am making a discord bot and want to use the user inputs to add names to a bracket.
However I am running into this error

```
Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg1' referenced before assignment
```

I have looked over questions with this same error however I couldn't find any that relate to my code, here it is.

```
@client.command()
async def bracketcreate(ctx):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://brackethq.com/maker/")

    teams = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')
    time.sleep(5)
    teams.click()


    await ctx.send("Send the name of player 1")
    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for("message", timeout=10, check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    except:
        await ctx.send("You took too long")
        return
    
    player1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="participant-1"]/div[3]/input')
    for _ in range(7):
        player1.send_keys('\ue003')
    player1.send_keys(msg.content)
    await ctx.send(f"Player 1 ({msg.content}) has been added")

    await ctx.send("Send the name of player 2")
    try:
        msg1 = await client.wait_for("message", time=9, check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    except:
        await ctx.send("You took too long")
        return
    
    player2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="participant-2"]/div[3]/input')
    for _ in range(7):
        player2.send_keys('\ue003')
    player2.send_keys(msg1.content)
    await ctx.send(f"Player 2 ({msg1.content} has been added)")
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: When the second `except:` block gets taken, you skip assigning to `msg1` - yet you still try to use it a few lines later.  This isn't a problem with `msg`, because its corresponding `except:` block contains a `return`.  Possibly the second block needs a corresponding `return`, possibly it needs to provide a default value for `msg1` that will make the following lines valid.

Comment: I added a return statement after the 2nd except, the code still provides the same error.

Comment: How should I go about writing it so it accepts a callback

Comment: some suggested reading https://realpython.com/python-async-features/

Answer (score -2):

Your code is giving an error because msg1 is defined in the scope of your try block. if you want to access it outside of your try block you would need to do something like

```
msg2 = None
    try:
        msg1 = await client.wait_for("message", time=9, check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    msg2 = msg1
    
    except:...

if (msg2 != None):
    player2.send_keys(msg1.content)
    await ctx.send(f"Player 2 ({msg1.content} has been added)")
```

Comment: That is not true. Python is scoped by function and class defenitions, not by indentation

Comment: Also the way your code is formatted would raise an exception on it's own.